# Split a character vector based on number of words in each element

Tags: r, vector, split

I have a character vector with different number of words for each of the elements, e.g

```
myVector <- c("a quick", "brown", "fox jumped over", "a", "deer")
```

I want to split the vector into two vectors, one with single-word elements and one with multi-word elements. How can I achieve it? I tried the following,

```
split.it <- function(x){

mult.vec <- character()

  if (length(unlist(strsplit(x,split=" ")))>1) {
    return(append(mult.vec, x))
  }

}
```

and then calling,

```
kj <- sapply(myVector , FUN=split.it)
```

but it did not give the desired result. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not very elegant but here is a very simple way:

```
vect_multi<-myVector[grepl(" ",myVector)]
vect_single<-myVector[!grepl(" ",myVector)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(stringr)
split(myVector,(str_count(myVector, "\\S+")>1)+1)
#$`1`
# [1] "brown" "a"     "deer" 

# $`2`
# [1] "a quick"         "fox jumped over"
```

Also, works when there are trailing/leading spaces

```
 myVector1 <- c(myVector, " foxy")
 split(myVector1,(str_count(myVector1, "\\S+")>1)+1)
 #$`1`
 #[1] "brown" "a"     "deer"  " foxy"

 #$`2`
 #[1] "a quick"         "fox jumped over"
```

Or modifying your function

```
split.it2 <- function(x){
lst <- strsplit(x, " ")
Length <- sapply(lst, length)
split(x, (Length>1) +1)
}

split.it2(myVector)
#$`1`
#[1] "brown" "a"     "deer" 

#$`2`
#[1] "a quick"         "fox jumped over"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `word_count` function in `qdap` package is a convenient wrapper. The function also has some potentially useful arguments:

```
library(qdap)
split(x = myVector, f = word_count(myVector) > 1)
# $`FALSE`
# [1] "brown" "a"     "deer" 
# 
# $`TRUE`
# [1] "a quick"         "fox jumped over"
```